# How to create a predicate that must meet two values with one being a list of values?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

With the following code how do I get a return that includes any of zip list but only records that have a purpose of street address? This currently returns matches for either the zip or the street address.

```
var zipPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<NameAddress>();
        List<string> zips = new List<string>();
        zips.Add("90210");
        zips.Add("90211");
        foreach (var item in zips)
        {
            zipPredicate = zipPredicate.Or(n=> n.ZIP.Contains(item));        
        }
            zipPredicate = zipPredicate.And(n=> n.Purpose=="Street Address");        
        var zipResult = from s in NameAddresses 
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(zipPredicate)
        select new{s.ID, s.ZIP, s.Purpose};

zipResult.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
var zipPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<NameAddress>();
    List<string> zips = new List<string>();
    zips.Add("90210");
    zips.Add("90211");
    foreach (var item in zips)
    {
        zipPredicate = zipPredicate.Or(n=> n.ZIP.Contains(item) && n.Purpose=="Street Address");        
    }        
    var zipResult = from s in NameAddresses 
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(zipPredicate)
    select new{s.ID, s.ZIP, s.Purpose};

zipResult.Dump();
```

**EDIT**

One more thing as well, if you want to drop building up the predicate, you should be able to do something like: `.Where(n=>zips.Contains(n.ZIP) && n.Purpose=="Street Address")` The important piece is that your entity property component comes inside the .Contains(). This would shorten your code to:

```
    List<string> zips = new List<string>();
    zips.Add("90210");
    zips.Add("90211");

    var zipResult = from s in NameAddresses 
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(n=>zips.Contains(n.ZIP) && n.Purpose=="Street Address")
    select new{s.ID, s.ZIP, s.Purpose};

zipResult.Dump();
```

Which I like better for readability. I would expect the query that ends up getting executed is the same either way.

Comment: I was trying that and not getting the correct results, then I realized that I had to change the PredicateBuilder.True to False.

Comment: That works if I have full zips but I forgot to mention that I need to find partial zips too. I.e. 90210 or 9021 or 90210-5533

Comment: I see... although the first method will still not match 90210 to 9021 will it?

Comment: Actually the first one that you listed did.

Comment: Interesting: I expected 'x'.Contains('y') to generate SQL like `'x' like '%y%'`, which in my first example I thought would result in `'9021' like '%90210%'` ... No I am curious, if I have time time later I am going use the profiler and see what is sent.

Comment: I'm also curious. The results I got were by testing with LinqPad